# How to Load, in Spring Boot Test, Basic Spring Application-Context Adding Only Named Components?

Tags: java, spring-boot, components, integration-testing, applicationcontext

## Original

I am trying to load, in a test of a Spring Boot (v2.3.8) application, *only named* components in a *basic* Spring application-context. More specifically, I want to load, in a test, a Spring application-context that configures at least logging, loading of external properties, validation (through Java Validation API), and `@Value`-plugging but without MVC, Data JPA, etc. In essence, I want to test, through a constraint-annotated interface (e.g. `@NotBlank`), a `@Service` that exercises only the local file-system (no MVC, Data JPA, or any other Spring Boot Test "slice") and has one data-member populated through `@Value`.

I have tried, to no avail, many annotations (and some of their inherent attributes), in different combination-subsets: e.g. `@SpringBootTest`, `@Configuration`, `@ContextConfiguration`, `@TestConfiguration`, `@TypeExcludeFilters`, etc. For example:

```
@Validated
public interface SomeService {
    String someMethod (@NotBlank String someParam);
}
...
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    @Value("${some.value}")
    private String someValue;

    @Override
    public String someMethod(String someParam) {
        // do something with local file-system,
        // with someValue in hand, and
        // knowing someParam not blank
    }
}
...
@SpringBootTest(classes={SomeServiceImpl.class},webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)
class SomeServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Test
    void throwConstraintViolationException_whenSomeParamNil() {
        assertThrows(
            ConstraintViolationException.class,
            ()->someService.someMethod(new String()));
    }
    ...
}
```

In this example, attribute `classes` of `@SpringBootTest` loads the cited class but obscures all of the *basics* (logging, validation, etc.) that I'm also seeking.

The following excerpt, from Craig Walls' "Spring Boot in Action," seems to be *exactly* what I'm seeking, but its main tool (`@SpringApplicationConfiguration`) is now deprecated (and its officially-recommended replacement - `@SpringBootTest` - does NOT behave equally, at least regarding attribute `classes`):

> Although @ContextConfiguration does a great job of loading the Spring application
> context, it doesn’t load it with the full Spring Boot treatment...SpringApplication
> not only loads the application context, but also enables logging, the loading of external
> properties (application.properties or application.yml), and other features of Spring
> Boot. If you’re using @ContextConfiguration, you won’t get those features. To get those features back in your integration tests, you can swap out @ContextConfiguration for Spring Boot’s @SpringApplicationConfiguration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=AddressBookConfiguration.class)
public class AddressServiceTests {
...
}
```

There, he gets the "full Spring Boot treatment" but adding *only* the class (`@Service`) he cites (not every `@Component`, `@Controller`, and `@Repository` of his domain).

How to do this today, without deprecated `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`?

### Update

I originally stated that my (not Craig Walls') example (namely `@SpringBootTest(classes={SomeServiceImpl.class},webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)`, although it loaded the cited class, obscured all of the *basics* of an application-context that Spring Boot would normally load. Through further experimentation, I have found that that statement was inaccurate, in that not *all* but, only, *some* of the basics are obscured, namely validation (implementation of Java Validation API). In other words, logging, loading of external properties, and @Value-plugging are, indeed, loaded/configured. I think that I must've gotten confused, in all of my many permutations/attempts.

Answer (score 1):

After yet more experimentation, I've found an answer. I can't say whether it's the best answer, but it's concise and certainly does the trick...

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;

// automatically configures validation (implementation of Java Validation API)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(ValidationAutoConfiguration.class)

// obscures/disables any otherwise-automatic web-environment;
// automatically configures logging, loading of external properties, and @Value-plugging;
// and, beyond that, adds to application-context only _cited_ classes/configuration-classes
@SpringBootTest(classes={SomeServiceImpl.class},webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)// full context loaded, if unqualified

public class SomeServiceTests {
...
}
```